# Updating View through binding doesnt' work

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, prism

I have a problem updating the layout of my listbox using MVVM with Prism 4.0.

I have no problem displaying my observablecollection to my listbox, but when I bind it to the DelegateCommand to add a new user or update a selected listbox item, it doesn't update but the underlying object is being updated. I tried using MessageBox.Show to give me the recent output and it did the changes, but in the view.xaml it doesn't update.

```
public class ProfileViewModel : DependencyObject
{
 public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
 public ObservableCollection<Persons> Persons { get; set; }

 public ProfileViewModel()
 {
   CreatePerson();
   SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save,CanSave);
 }

 private void Save()
 {
   Person[0].LastUpdated = DateTime.Now
   Persons.Add(new Persons { FIrstName = "Bob", LastName "Bob," LastUpdated=DateTime.Now});
 }

 private bool CanSave()
 {
  return true;
 }

 public void CreatePerson()
 {
   this.Persons = new ObservableCollection<Persons>();
   Persons.Add(new Persons { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", LastUpdated = DateTime.Now});Persons.Add(new Persons { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", LastUpdated = DateTime.Now});
Persons.Add(new Persons { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", LastUpdated = DateTime.Now});
 }
}
}
```

ProfilePage.Xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Name="ListBoxItem">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                            <Button Content="_Save" Command={Binding Source={Static Resource ProfileViewModel{, Path=SaveCommand}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

ProflilePage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class ProfilePage : Window
 {
   private ProfileViewModel _vm;

   [Dependency]
   public ProfileViewModel VM
   {
     set { _vm = value; this.DataContext = _vm; }
   }

   public ProfilePage()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
   }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
 {
   IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
   ProfileViewModel source = new ProfileViewModel();
   ProfilePage window = container.Resolve<ProfilePage>();
   window.show();
 }
```

My Persons class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and has a getter setter of LastName,FirstName and LastUpdated.

Comment: Can you post a little more of the code? The Listbox code you have does not match the VM or the Person class.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a wrong copy paste on my view. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need the [DataContextProxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) to make bindings working. The ElementName binding will also work on ListBox

Comment: If I will use the ElementName binding, then I am breaking the rules of MVVM pattern.

Comment: Don't be a slave to pattern's. =)

Comment: It's not being a slave to patterns, it's called software architecting. Not doing a small system to implement to break the rules.

Comment: @Inluis - Use DataContextProxy, that will be MVVM without anchoring to another UI element. I think SL5 will do what you need with binding improvements

Answer (score 0):

If I am looking at this correctly, you need to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the VM as well.  The View cannot see the events fired from the Model.

Comment: It doesn't work. I fired the INotifyPropertyChanged and the OnPropertyChanged and passed the ObservableCollection<Persons> Persons property. Nothing was changed.